# How can I increase the width or height of the div it is in while moving an item independently?

Tags: html, css

I want to prevent the "Salgın" text from hitting other articles while moving it in the green divin. I saw that it is possible to do this with the "relative" code. The question is: While moving the text, the height and width of the green divin increase according to its position at the same time. When I give padding or margin to the text "Salgın", the others should not be affected, but the height or width of the green divin will increase.

Or let me put it like this: When I give a position to the "Salgın" article, the height or width of the divin it is located in should increase, but while this happens, the position of the other articles should not change in any way
and must be all in the same div.

[image]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #444444;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
}

#hepsi {
  background-color: #FC0;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

#deneme {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#sol {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #666;
  line-height: 0;
}

#orta {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #0C0;
}

#sag {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #FF6;
}

#kitapfoto {
  width: 186px;
  height: 273px;
}

#kitapadi {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#yayinyili {
  ,
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#kitapturu {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#okuyucupuani {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#benimpuanim {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="hepsi">
  <div id="deneme">
    <div id="sol"> <img id="kitapfoto" src="img/s9PBDwAAQBAJ.jpg" /> </div>
    <div id="orta">
      <div id="kitapadi">Salgın</div>
      <div id="yayinyili">Yayın yılı : 2013</div>
      <div id="kitapturu">Tür : Zombi</div>
      <div id="okuyucupuani">Okuyucu Puanı : 8.8/10</div>
      <div id="benimpuanim">Benim Puanım : 6.8/10</div>
    </div>
    <div id="sag">Sağ </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When you say moving, what do you mean? Window resize? Dragging an item? Can you include the code the will make it move?

Comment: Do not get me wrong because I stated this: D I am a beginner and I explain it like this. The green area is a div. There are separate divs that say "Salgın" "Çıkış Yılı: 2013" in the div. I want the size of the green divin to increase when I move these divs. For example, "Salgın" is "position: relative " "top: 200px;" I want the green div size to increase when I enter the code, and while this is happening, it should not multiply to other articles" Example: Release year: 2013 "in any way. I mean it should act as" relative "code , but it should increase the div size while acting relative.

Comment: No problem Haktan. Do you have a working example of what you are trying to achieve? A Demo?

Comment: I don't have a working sample.I hope you can understand what I'm saying, because I use translate.In the simplest terms, I want other divs in a div to be independent of each other.with the" relative " code, this is possible.But what I want is for div to raise and lower its size when there is this Independence.I want the Yesil div size to rise when I give the" Salgın " top : 200px;.when I give "relative" and the coordinate code, the "Salgın" sign goes out of div.

Answer (score 1):

This might be completely wrong but is this what you are after?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #444444;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
}

#hepsi {
  background-color: #FC0;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

#deneme {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 740px;
    margin: auto;
}

#sol {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: #666;
  line-height: 0;
  max-height: 273px;
}

#orta {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #0C0;
}

#orta:hover #kitapadi{
  order: 6;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

#orta:hover #yayinyili{
  margin-top: 34px;
}


#sag {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #FF6;
  max-height: 273px;
}

#kitapfoto {
  width: 186px;
  height: 273px;
}

#kitapadi {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  order: 1;
}

#yayinyili {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  order: 2;
}

#kitapturu {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  order: 3;
}

#okuyucupuani {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  order: 4;
}

#benimpuanim {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  order: 5;
}
```

```html
<div id="hepsi">
  <div id="deneme">
    <div id="sol"> <img id="kitapfoto" src="img/s9PBDwAAQBAJ.jpg" /> </div>
    <div id="orta">
      <div id="kitapadi">Salgın</div>
      <div id="yayinyili">Yayın yılı : 2013</div>
      <div id="kitapturu">Tür : Zombi</div>
      <div id="okuyucupuani">Okuyucu Puanı : 8.8/10</div>
      <div id="benimpuanim">Benim Puanım : 6.8/10</div>
    </div>
    <div id="sag">Sağ </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very very much.Many thanks for the effort you gave.Im sorry for my late writng.I want it not to hit other posts while moving the "Salgın" article.You provided it, but it happens when the user comes to it.When I automatically give a position when I write code, I want the Yesil field to grow and the divin on the right and left sides not to be affected.The fact is that "Salgın" has its own dimension.When I give that post or dive "top:250px" it should go down and the length of the Green field should increase when it goes"Salgın" is out of green space and it will increase in length.

Comment: I have updated the above snippet. When you say "when the user comes to it", are you referring to hover?

As far as I am aware, you cannot automatically increase the height of a parent element when you position one of its child elements outside its boundaries. You either change the height of the child element or its parent while keeping the position static.